# Assembly.GetTypes() misbehaviour

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I'm on a team developing a Add-in for excel. My set up is VS 2015 Enterprise fully updated. My colleague set up is VS 2013 Premium fully updated. The project we are working on is set to use .Net 4.5.

There's a point in the code that `GetTypes()` is called and iterated over and this is where things get weird. My enumeration returns **198** types. My colleagues return **130**-something. And more than that, the order in which the types are enumerated over is completely different (think mine come in a random order, and theirs come sorted or something).

The point is that this is happening in a very crucial part of the code, and is screwing the add-in for me... You see, based on the enumeration, the wrong class is being loaded for me, and i'm reluctant to alter this piece of code, because i'm new in the team, and the add-in has no unit tests and theres a lot of functionalities...

Any one care to explain why the number of types returned are different (198 vs 130-something) and why the ordering of the array is different?

Comment: You are going to have to show us the code in question before we can really say anything about it.

Comment: +1 to the previous commenter as well as this: must be something about the private types returned or not. About the order: try to sort things up urself on both cases like by the types name and\or their generics.

Comment: Also: What assembly are you calling this on? A third party, one compiled by yourself or one compiled by your co-workers?

Comment: @BradleyUffner there is actually NOTHING special about the code! a given assembly is loaded, and then `var marry = loadedAssembly.GetTypes()`

Comment: @NineBerry im calling this on my own assembly... 3rd part soft here is only the IoC (Ninject)... compilation is done locally...